# Creating time series from NetCDF with multiple values to multiple points on ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, netcdf, arcgis-10.5, time-series

I am using ArcGIS Desktop to read and extract netcdf files which have data on longitudes, latitudes and daily temperature over several years. I have separate shapefile with postcodes and the goal is to create a temperature timeseries for each postcode.

I am using ModelBuilder:

[image: see attached image]

In my model, I initially created raster file from the netcdf file (daily_meantemp_Layer1), I then select the time dimension for each day of the month using the 'Select by Dimension' tool, then for each raster created by I extract the temperature values using the 'Extract Multi Values to Points'. The problem is that my final extracted values are all the same, I have added a table to show what I am getting

[image: see attached table] .

It appears that my select by dimension bit of the model is selecting information from the only one or two days.

In a separate model I tried saving all the individual rasters in .gdb and extracting from them using the 'abs' command, this too gives me the same value across all days.

What am I doing wrong?

I am open to doing this using script its just I wouldnt know where to start!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same issue, I think ArcGIS is just opening the first variable of data and not everything in the series, I am looking at dissolved silica and although the .nc file is over 400MB it only shows the first month, not the remaining 119.